# if, else if not working javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was coding my own JARVIS (sort of, nothing closer to the iron man one)
but the else if statement is not working

```
function ttalk(code) {
    varpo = code;
    if (varpo == "good morning") {
        var currentdate = new Date();
        var hours = currentdate.getHours();
        if (hours >= 12)  {
            dn=PM;
        } else {
            dn=AM;
        }
        varso = "Good Morning, Sir. The time now is "  + currentdate.getHours() + "  " + currentdate.getMinutes() + dn;
    } else if (varpo == "hello") {
        varso = "reading your F.B. Notifications.";
    } else {
        varso = "Not Got That, Sir";
    }

    speaker.speak("en", varso);
}
```

When I say `Good Morning` it does speak `time now`, but whenever I say `hello` it says `Not Got That, Sir`, why?

Full code with a input field to test try this

```
Enter Text To Play:
<input id="text">&nbsp;(Recognized text for voice will also appear here)
<br><br>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="stalk()">Talk It!</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="listen()">Recognize My Voice</button>

<script>
    var speaker = new RobotSpeaker();
    var listener = new AudioListener();

function stalk() {
 var varpo = document.getElementById("text").value;
 if (varpo == "good morning") {
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var hours = currentdate.getHours();
          if (hours >= 12)  { dn=PM;} else {dn=AM;}
       varso = "Good Morning, Sir. The time now is "  + currentdate.getHours() + "  " + currentdate.getMinutes() + dn;
} 
else if (varpo == "hello") {
  varso = "reading your F.B. Notifications.";
}
else {
   varso = "Not Got That, Sir";
}
        speaker.speak("en", varso);
    }
```

Comment: I am surprised it got "Good Morning" since you have capitals in that...

Comment: Did you try logging `varpo` to console?

Comment: It says *"reading your F.B. Notifications."* if I pass in `'hello'`. You must be passing something else. Try `var varpo = code.trim();`

Comment: No i say it actually and api converts it to "good morning".

Comment: I am not sure. But can you please try after adding toLowerCase() while comparing string in javascript?

Comment: Its working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qo00ydka/ The error is something else, probably your api which converts voice to input strings.

Comment: its google speak recognition API

Comment: have you tried to log the variable `varpo` to check the value?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and its working fine just you need to change PM and AM to "PM" and "AM" respectively.

Below is output when I executed with "good morning"

Good Morning, Sir. The time now is 14  58PM

When you will pass "Good Morning" it shows as below. Due to case sensitive.

Not Got That, Sir

Comment: the problem was the string is generated by `google speak recognition API`.. if you input  the string manually, it surely works

Comment: Yupp @DyrandzFamador that's what I want to say the problem is neither about cases nor about trimming.

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt, have you tried to check the value of variable `code` to check the actual string value?

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt, what i mean is to check the generated text from `google speak recognition API`..  is your text was generated by a speech recognition?

Answer (score 0):

please try this, use internal string comparison which javascript offers.

```
function ttalk(code) {
    varpo = code;
    if (varpo.localeCompare("good morning")==0) {
        var currentdate = new Date();
        var hours = currentdate.getHours();
        if (hours >= 12)  {
            dn=PM;
        } else {
            dn=AM;
        }
        varso = "Good Morning, Sir. The time now is "  + currentdate.getHours() + "  " + currentdate.getMinutes() + dn;
    } else if (varpo.localeCompare("hello")==0) {
        varso = "reading your F.B. Notifications.";
    } else {
        varso = "Not Got That, Sir";
    }

    speaker.speak("en", varso);
}
```

Thanks
Amit